# MDX - Calculate grand total while using IIF

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to use IIF to include some dimension/attributes in a calculation. I am able to filter the dimensions, but the measures dont calculate the Grand Total. Below is the function i am using. (I hope you are able to disregard the use of danish language)

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Børn medtaget i årsrapport]
AS  
sum (iif(
    exists({[Ernaering].[NSU - Type].&[Udelukkende amning]}, [Ernaering].[NSU - Type].CurrentMember).Count = 1 AND 
    exists({[Ernaeringsperiode].[Måned].&[0]:[Ernaeringsperiode].[Måned].&[8]}, [Ernaeringsperiode].[Måned].CurrentMember).Count = 1
    , [Measures].[Antal børn]
    , null
))
, 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0;-#,##0",
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

[Measures].[Antal børn]  is distinct count, and this must also apply to the grand total.

I hope anyone has an answer, thanks in advance.

Best Regards
Jens Henrik

Comment: I think you shoul create a member for each with a null condition for each count you need, it will simplify the result and resolve your iif condition.